# How to web-scrape multiple page with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've seen several solutions to scrape multiple pages from a website, but couldn't make it work on my code.

At the moment, I have this code, that is working to scrape the first page. And I would like to create a loop to scrape all the page of the website (from page 1 to 5)

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/raduulea/Documents/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000?page=1')

import time
time.sleep(10)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"result-xl"})
title=[]
address=[]
price=[]
surface=[]
desc=[]

for result in results:
    title.append(result.find("div", {"class":"title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
    address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
    price.append(result.find("div", {"class":"xl-price rangePrice"}).get_text().strip())
    surface.append(result.find("div", {"class":"xl-surface-ch"}).get_text().strip())
    desc.append(result.find("div", {"class":"xl-desc"}).get_text().strip())


df = pd.DataFrame({"Title":title,"Address":address,"Price:":price,"Surface" : surface,"Description":desc})
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code.It will loop through all pages not only 5 pages.Check the next button if available click on it else break the wile loop.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/raduulea/Documents/chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get('https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre')

import time

time.sleep(10)

Title = []
address = []
price = []
surface = []
desc = []
page=2
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result-xl"})
    for result in results:
        Title.append(result.find("div", {"class": "title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
        address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
        price.append(result.find("div", {"class": "xl-price rangePrice"}).get_text().strip())
        surface.append(result.find("div", {"class": "xl-surface-ch"}).get_text().strip())
        desc.append(result.find("div", {"class": "xl-desc"}).get_text().strip())
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.next")) > 0:
        url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/?page={}".format(page)
        driver.get(url)
        page += 1
        #It will traverse for only 5 pages as you are after if want more page just comment the below if block
        if int(page)>5:
        break
    else:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": Title, "Address": address, "Price:": price, "Surface": surface, "Description": desc})
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
Selenium does indeed scrawl all the pages, however, it only gather the data from the first page. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Ok I got it.If you click on page it will navigate to same page.Updated the code try now.

Comment: Ok !! 
So it took me a while to make it work I don't know why, but I think it's good !! 
Thank you so much !

Comment: But for a obscure reason I have this error message, sometimes directly, sometimes after a couple pages...

couldn't write the whole message here, so here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ZH5R6ko

Comment: You are getting this because after few pages traverse some of the element is not present on the page.in that case you have to use try catch block with your result.find() option .if element there append else append 'NONE' like that

Comment: you're probably right, but I have no clue on how to add that in the code unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` library to save data into csv file

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time

def main():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
    ua = UserAgent()
    a = ua.random
    user_agent = ua.random

    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/raduulea/Documents/chromedriver", options=options)

    title=[]
    address=[]
    price=[]
    surface=[]
    desc=[]

    for i in range(1,6):
        url = 'https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000?page='+str(i)
        driver.get(url)
        scrap_data(driver,title,address,price,surface,desc)

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Title":title,"Address":address,"Price:":price,"Surface" : surface,"Description":desc})
    df.to_csv("output.csv")


def scrap_data(driver,title,address,price,surface,desc):
    time.sleep(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"result-xl"})

    for result in results:
        title.append(result.find("div", {"class":"title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
        address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
        price.append(result.find("div", {"class":"xl-price rangePrice"}).get_text().strip())
        surface.append(result.find("div", {"class":"xl-surface-ch"}).get_text().strip())
        desc.append(result.find("div", {"class":"xl-desc"}).get_text().strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

csv file o/p:

```
,Title,Address,Price:,Surface,Description
0,Appartement,4000 Liège,279.000 €,180 m²     3 ch.,Appartement au 8ème étage avec vue sur Meuse
1,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liège (Hognoul),645.000 €,345 m²     6 ch.,Hognoul - immeuble à appartements !
2,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liège,195.000 €,100 m²     2 ch.,Immeuble à appartement
3,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liège,320.000 €,229 m²     4 ch.,"immeuble de rapport , 1 commerce et 3 logements"
4,Immeuble mixte,4000 Liège,670.000 €,324 m²     3 ch.,"Immeuble atypique : triplex, centre de bien-être, ch. hôtes"
5,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liege,635.000 €,360 m²     9 ch.,LIEGE - Immeuble à appartements remis à neuf !
6,Maison,4000 Liège,245.000 €,225 m²     5 ch.,Opportunité - rendement de 6% NET
7,Immeuble mixte,4000 Liège,339.000 €,348 m²     2 ch.,Ensemble de 2 immeubles mixtes
8,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liege,1.250.000 €,1000 m²     14 ch.,LIEGE - Ensemble immobilier de rapport !
9,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liège,310.000 €,3 ch.,Maison de commerce et logements Hyper centre
10,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liège,660.000 €,285 m²     5 ch.,Hôtel de Maître avec terrasse à prox. rue de la Casquette
11,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liège,1.100.000 €,722 m²,!!!!! OPTION !!!! Immeuble de rapport hyper centre
12,Immeuble mixte,4000 Liège,925.000 €,390 m²     6 ch.,Ensemble immobilier dans le Parc de Cointe
13,Immeuble mixte,4000 Liège,299.000 €,550 m²,batiment commercial de 550m2 environ . dispose d'une vitrine a ...
14,Immeuble mixte,4000 Liège,211.500 €,220 m²,"AGENCE S'ABSTENIR
Lot de 3 bureaux (dont deux loués pour ..."
15,Immeuble mixte,4000 LIEGE,86.000 €,1 ch.,CENTRE-VILLE: MAISON DE COM.+HABITATION
16,Immeuble à appartements,4000 Liège,70.000 €,3 ch.,"Maison de rapport sise à Liège rue Chéri, 49"
17,Immeuble à appartements,4000 LIEGE,399.000 €,6 ch.,"IMM. DE RAPPORT: 2 REZ COM., 4 STUDIOS+1 APPART."
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your code but according to your question I hope this is useful for readers

you can use driver.back();

```
urls = ['https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com']
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get(url[0])
html_example0 = driver.page_source
driver.back()
driver.get(url[1])
html_example1 = driver.page_source
```

In upper code when I dont use `driver.back()`;  I get same response for driver.page_source while the websites is not the same.

with using the back() method of driver; I get The desired result.

In fact, It seems that this method press the  back button to return to the previous page in the browser.